# Keyboard autocorrect function to catch common typos?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I find myself making the same errors repeatedly on my Dvorak Keyboard. For example instead of typing:

```
I'm
```

It comes out as

```
I"m
```

because my finger lingers on the shift key. This is similar to typing `THe` instead of `The`.

Is there any program I can install in linux to catch common errors like this as I'm typing and autocorrect them? Preferably something that operates system wide instead of just for a particular application?

Comment: Maybe an `expect` script could handle CLI programs.